# Sobrescrever funções do php

Tags: php, funções, sobrescrita

Estou trabalhando na segurança do meu site e gostaria de saber se um usuário malicioso pode sobrescrever alguma função php do meu site caso por ventura ele descubra qual o nome dessa função?

Comment: Existe casos bem raros que isso pode acontecer. Escrevi um exemplo, da uma olhada: https://ideone.com/IcHcqz

Comment: depende se ele tiver acesso ao teu servidor é obvio que sim, e tambem pode subscrever utilizando [shellinjection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Command_Injection)

Comment: Só se você estiver usando algo como `eval($_GET['xyz']);` e as funções forem "anonimas" (closure) em variaveis. Não tem como o usuário acessar diretamente o que esta em tempo de execução no teus scripts back-end a não ser que você crie esta brecha.